# JavaFX blocking native key event handling for treeview

Tags: treeview, javafx-2, keyevent

I would like to change handling of key pressed events for example to do something else when user press up/down arrows but when i add eventHandler by setOnKeyPressed/setOnKeyReleased i cant stop native handling of those keys.

Example:

```
treeView.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    private KeyCodeCombination prevNodeKeyCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.UP);
    private KeyCodeCombination nextNodeKeyCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.DOWN);

    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (prevNodeKeyCombination.match(event))
        {
            selectPrevSibling();
        }
        else if (nextNodeKeyCombination.match(event))
        {
            selectNextSibling();
        }

        event.consume(); // i try to block anything that goes by
    }
});
```

Any idea how to override native key handling, if necessary i can try extend TreeView if that helps in something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override native handling of event use addEventFilter in my case it was:

```
treeView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() { ... }
```

Comment: Impotent to call event.consume(); within EventHandler